# Loading different views for iPad & iPhone in Titanium Alloy

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have different views created for iPad and iPhone. The folder hierarchy is views/ios/iPhone/index.xml and views/ios/iPad/index.xml

I have only one controller index.js.

My question is, is it possible to write conditional code such that the index.js loads the appropriate XML based on whether the device is an iPad or iPhone?

I know this much of the code

index.js

```
if(Ti.Platform.osname =="iphone")
{
   //Load iPhone xml
}
if(Ti.Platform.osname =="ipad")
{
   //Load iPad xml
}
```

Could someone please help me out with this? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Having one controller with two views can be considered controllers without views, you can do it with the `require` tag in xml and with `Alloy.createController('foo').getView();` in the controller.

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Views_without_Controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best approach, but I believe this will accomplish what you want.

```
var myController = null;

if(Ti.Platform.osname =="iphone")
{
   myController = Alloy.createController('ios/iPhone/index');
}
if(Ti.Platform.osname =="ipad")
{
   myController = Alloy.createController('ios/iPad/index');
}
```

I use the built-in properties to allow me to use a single controller.

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
  <View id="container" formFactor="tablet">
    <Label id="tabletLabel">Tablet</Label>
  </View>
  <View id="container" formFactor="handheld">
    <Label id="phoneLabel">iPhone</Label>
  </View>
</Alloy>
```

This will only create the elements inside the appropriate form factor.  So if the device is a tablet, the phoneLabel won't even exist after the screen is created.  This way you have a single controller creating both the screens allowing you to reuse the functionality of the logic in the index.js file.  This helps you reduce repeating code.

Comment: The code gives an error couldn't find module alloy/controllers/ios/iPhone/index. So I'm assuming it goes and searches for a corresponding controller for each iPhone and iPad.

Comment: I had it saying index.js and that should have said index.xml.